# How to filter object at multiple levels in JQ?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json like this but much longer:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "home network configuration",
    "description": "home utilities",
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "id": "6500b67e",
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
        "state": "UNALLOCATED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "description": "lab experiments",
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "id": "1209b90d",
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
        "state": "ALLOCATED"
      },
      {
        "id": "99e08ca4",
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
        "state": "UNALLOCATED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to query with jq and obtain the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "home network configuration"
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
      },
      {
        "name": "100-200",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

or even this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "home network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
  }
]
```

So far I was able to extract the network name at the first level with:

```
.[] | {name}
```

I could also extract the definedRanges with:

```
.[].definedRanges[] | {name,beginIPv4Address,endIPv4Address}
```

But I can't figure out how to merge the two with jq.

I solved the problem with a very simple python script (7 lines of code) but now I'd like to understand how to do the same with jq, out of curiosity.

Comment: Why doesn't the last element in the output not have a `definedRange.name` property? Why is `beginIPv4Addresses` sometimes prefixed with `definedRanges`, but not always? Why is the `definedRange.name` property missing from the last element?

Comment: @knittl there are two main elements: "home network" and "lab network".
Then "home network" has only one defined range while "lab network has two defined range".
I think the json is quite consistent :)

Comment: Is it consistent? Your expected output contains 3 objects with 3-4 properties each, the properties being `name`, `definedRanges.name` (missing from last object), `definedRanges.beginIPv4Address`, `beginIPv4Address`, `definedRanges.endIPv4Address`, and `endIPv4Address`. How is it defined which objects will get the prefix, which objects won't, and whether to add the name of the range? The second object even has mixed properties (name with prefix, the rest without)

Comment: @knittl, got the point, I edited the question. Now should be consistent, thanks for spotting that out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you were close. Here's how you put those together:

```
map({name, definedRanges: .definedRanges | map({name, beginIPv4Address, endIPv4Address})})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tHkRlLUV3K-)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The '*or even this*' can be achieved using:

```
map(.name as $name | .definedRanges[] | { name, beginIPv4Address, endIPv4Address} | with_entries(.key = "definedRanges." + .key) | .name = $name)
```

Which yields:

```json
[
  {
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
    "name": "home network configuration"
  },
  {
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
    "name": "lab network configuration"
  },
  {
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200",
    "name": "lab network configuration"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/m7gEiLLqkE4)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at solutions to produce one or the other desired output:

```
map(
  { name }
  + (.definedRanges[] | {
      "definedRanges.name": .name,
      "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": .beginIPv4Address,
      "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": .endIPv4Address
  }))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "home network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200"
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200"
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges.name": "100-200",
    "definedRanges.beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.100",
    "definedRanges.endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.200"
  }
]
```

Producing the first kind of output is even simpler (IMHO it reads a bit more straightforward):

```
map({
    name,
    definedRanges: .definedRanges | map({ name, beginIPv4Address, endIPv4Address })
})
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "home network configuration",
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "name": "100-2001",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.101",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "lab network configuration",
    "definedRanges": [
      {
        "name": "100-2002",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.102",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.202"
      },
      {
        "name": "100-2003",
        "beginIPv4Address": "192.168.090.103",
        "endIPv4Address": "192.168.090.203"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```